# In mathematics, what is an $N \times N \times N$ matrix?

Tags: matrices, tensors

In mathematics, what is an $N \times N \times N$ matrix? I think this is a tensor but definitions of tensors that I have read are so overly complicated and verbose that I have trouble understanding them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'ts a tensor. But so are normal numbers, vectors, and matrices which can be considered 1X1 tensor, 1Xn tensor, mXn Tensor. All data structures of this form (mXnX...)are what are called Tensors.

Answer (score 4):

Tensors in general are multilinear coordinate-free objects that **can be represented** with respect to some basis by a multi-dimensional arrays indexed appropriately. Just like you can represent a bilinear form $B \colon V \times V \rightarrow  \mathbb{F}$ when $V$ is an $n$-dimensional vector space (or a linear map $T \colon V \rightarrow V$) by a $n \times n$ matrix and use a matrix (together with a choice of basis) to define a bilinear form (or a linear map) on $V$, you can represent a multi-linear map $B' \colon V \times V \times V \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ ("a tensor") by an $n \times n \times n$ dimensional array of scalars and use such an array to define a multi-linear map on $V$.

Answer (score 2):

You can think of a rank three tensor as a three dimensional array. A matrix is a rank two tensor, or a two dimensional array. A vector then is a rank one tensor and scalar a rank zero.  This is a simplification of the subject of tensors, but it's useful to think of them as a generalization of matrices.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of tensors as [multidimensional arrays.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor#As_multidimensional_arrays)

Answer (score 0):

If you are having trouble with tensors, try this:
Imagine that you want to locate a point in 3-dimensional Cartesian plane. You need (x,y,z) coordinates to locate the point. Now imagine that each of these points has a numerical value. Then this three dimensional plane with these numerical value will constitute a matrix. If the length of x, y and z axes, each is N, then you get $N\times N\times N$ matrix.